# How to get the camera app to take multiple photos

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I have managed to get the camera app take one photo and return it to the activity using `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`.

How do I get the camera take multiple photos and return them to the activity?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I'll try to explain the basic steps. First create your view (preview) of the camera:

```
/** A basic Camera preview class */
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    mCamera = camera;

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
    // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
    // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

    if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
      // preview surface does not exist
      return;
    }

    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
      // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here

    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Now, change your activity's layout to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
/>

<Button
android:id="@+id/button_capture"
android:text="Capture"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In your manifest, add this line to your activity:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

Now, on your activity, change your onCreate with this:

```
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create an instance of Camera
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout)   findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
}
```

Define the Picture callback in order to receive the photo in JPEG format:

```
private PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {

@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    if (pictureFile == null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: " +
            e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
        fos.write(data);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
};
```

Now, if you want to take a picture, call this method how much time you want (pay attention to the release of the camera maybe)

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
```

P.S: Camera is deprecated, if you want, try to use Camera2

For all information, take a look there: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I've included the essential parts. Sorry for this, I hope everything is clear!

Answer (score 0):

it cannot be done by `Intent`
if you want to capture multiple photos and then return all of them to your app, you have to write a camera activity yourself.

Comment: this is mostly a comment.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain I disagree. It points that it cannot be done the way he was planning (see the `android-camera-intent` tag) and it tells that approach in which can be possible to do.

Comment: @Ryderz it's not a "2 lines of code" solution like an Intent. I would suggest use this library to interface the camera https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera and from it you will have to add some extra UI to "accept" etc